# Chromecast not casting when waking from sleep

Tags: java, android, chromecast, google-cast

I'm building an app that wakes the phone from sleep and then starts casting.
The way I've done is by making a BroadcastReceiver that start an activity like so

```
WakeLocker.acquire(context);
Intent intentAlarm = new Intent(context, AlarmRingingActivity.class);
intentAlarm.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_USER_ACTION |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP |
          Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intentAlarm.setAction("ACTION_VIEW");
context.startActivity(intentAlarm);
```

in the AlarmRingingActivity I then use this code

```
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);

    mMediaRouteButton = (MediaRouteButton) findViewById(R.id.media_route_button);
    CastButtonFactory.setUpMediaRouteButton(getApplicationContext(), mMediaRouteButton);

    mCastContext = CastContext.getSharedInstance(this);

    mSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            // These are the framework-supported intents
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_AUDIO)
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_REMOTE_PLAYBACK)
            .build();
    mMediaRouter = MediaRouter.getInstance(this);
    for (MediaRouter.RouteInfo route : mMediaRouter.getRoutes()) {
        if (route.getName().equals("Min Stue")) {
            mMediaRouter.selectRoute(route);
            Log.d("MyAlarm", "Size:" + mMediaRouter.getRoutes().size());
        }
        Log.d("MyAlarm", route + "");
    }
```

This all works if I don't lock the phone and it starts casting. However if I lock the phone, it doesn't start casting. It shows the casting icon and I can stop the casting, however it doesn't actually cast to the screen. Also if the phone sleeps for too long, it "forgets" the media routes, and the only media route available is the phone itself.

So my questions are:

1. How can I cast, when waking up from sleep/unlocking the phone?
2. How can I prevent the app from "forgetting" the media routes?

Comment: From this [thread](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-chromecast/332428-how-wake-up-chromecast-standby.html), taking off the HDMI extender appears to be the workaround to wake the chromecast. These forums: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/NzqSGkIvLqQ and https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromecast/2dP-yk4kqsQ might also help. Make sure you are using the power adapter plug that came in the Chromecast box and not powered by a USB port.

Comment: The problem isn't that the Chromecast is sleeping. If I cast some content while the TV is turned off, it turns the tv on and starts casting. The problem comes when the phone is woken up from sleep mode and is told to start casting. I can see where the confusion would come from though.